# XMLhttpRequest not able to load when data is sent to it express node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

I am baffled as to why this does not work. Using this same code in other places with different purposes, it works fine, but for some reason now trying to get an XMLhttpRequest with ajax is not capable of picking up anything.

My best guess is that there is only so many permitted requests until it doesn't work anymore?

Here is the client side code:

```
function onError() {
  console.log('error');
}
console.log('page loaded')
var res5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url5 = '/hello';
res5.open('POST',url5,true);
res5.addEventListener('load',onLoad5);
res5.addEventListener('error',onError);
function onLoad5() {
  console.log("SOMETHING")
  console.log('da')
  console.log('hello')
}
  var a = {potato: "blue"};
  $.post('/hello', a);
```

Here is the server in node:

```
app.post('/hello', function(req, res) {
  console.log('triggers')
  var dataToSend = '{"Error":"yes"}';
  res.send(dataToSend);
})
```

The server gets the request, as 'triggers' is logged, but on the client side none of the logs in the onload5() work, thus the onload5() never picks up anything.

I am not sure how to debug this to figure out what is the issue or how to solve it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you've set up `var res5 = new XMLHttpRequest();` ... then never actually initiate the request (where's the `res5.send()` for example) - all you do is revert to jQueery to do `$.post('/hello', a);` .... which won't actually trigger `onLaod5` since it's completely unrelated

Comment: try replacing that jqueery with `res5.send(JSON.stringify(a))`

Comment: Hmm, I am confused. That altered nothing. It just was an alternative to post, I still get it on the server. But its the server sending to the client that seems to not be working?

Comment: check the request in the browser *developer* tools

Comment: Oh nice. Didn't know that existed. I see the request, well a request, from that js page, thus the request happens, but I'm not sure what to do with this data

Comment: a get request  .

Comment: a get request? not possible, `res5.open('POST',url5,true);` clearly it's a POST request - are you perhaps dealing with a form submission or something else you have not shown

Comment: It states, "method: GET", there are no other actions that happen on that js page. No form submission. Ill try making a completely new client-side js page to ensure nothing else is going on behind the scenes

Comment: same thing happened

Comment: what does that even mean?

Comment: I moved the client side js code you see above into its own javascript page called testing.js, and added a test html page with nothing in it but testing.js script added. No difference is made, in the network of console I see "Request Method: GET" and other info

Comment: Ill screenshot and edit it into the post so its clear

Comment: Hmm, this is baffling indeed. It now worked for some reason when in the new page entirely, after the second attempt. But when I move it back to the old page it no longer works. Could in theory something be possibly blocking it from happening? Like another request in progress that is unable to finish?

Comment: you haven't shown the AJAX in developer tools request/response as far as I can tell ... just the loading of the script file

Comment: Oh, my bad. Where could I find that?

Comment: in the browser developer tools .......

Comment: Wow. I think this was just replit(I know, terrible, I don't know why I still use it). After refreshing the page in insanity multiple times, it just worked? You fixed it, thank you, altering it to send() instead of jquery worked, but I just didnt know it until after a while when replit processed it maybe.